# Test-Driven Development "Barriers to Entry"?

Tags: tdd

I'm in the process of doing a study on Test-Driven Development and one of the discussion points is the "Barrier to Entry" associated with TDD. Does anyone have any experience around this area, on any projects you've worked on that decided not to use TDD because the barrier to entry was too high?

From what I can tell the only barrier to entry is knowledge (and as such experience) of individual developers, with most not being entirely accustomed to the process and it being slightly alien. Financially it seems to be very appealing given most of the market leading tools are open source, freely available, well documented and well supported.

Thoughts/feelings appreciated.

Thanks,

EDIT - does anyone know of any high profile quotes of people advocating TDD? Would love to see how high it goes up the chain. Cheers.

Answer (score 14):

Some barriers include:

1. An existing code base which doesn't lend itself to unit testing.
2. A problem domain that is hard to unit test meaningfully, such as GUI work or integrations with third party systems.
3. A perception of integration problems over unit problems (in other words, if it doesn't work end to end it doesn't do anything, so what is the point of testing the unit).
4. A mindset that wants to design ahead of time and have a clear system design rather than have tests drive design
5. A political culture where design is done by a different person/group than development, and that design is not unit-test friendly.
6. An inability to get over the fact that TDD is not about testing for conformance (arguments like "the one who writes the tests shouldn't be the one who codes it, they will be too lenient on themselves" and such variants).
7. It isn't they way they have coded until now, so the shift is harder.
8. Sometimes a certain test can be hard to set up, so the method will get abandoned because it "feels" slower.
9. Design requirements that don't lend themselves to evolving design well or at all (think Nuclear Plant control software or other systems were actual lives depend on their functioning correctly).
10. If everyone isn't running the test before checking in code, tests start to break often for wrong reasons (that is the intended behavior of the code changed, but the test didn't keep up, so the test is wrong, not the code) so they can be perceived as a drag.

Answer (score 7):

In terms of barriers to entry, effectively, because you are explicitly writing tests that must pass before code is considered to be complete, the lead time in the dev cycle involved in getting functional code is longer.  Now, when using TDD, you're effectively guaranteeing a certain level of quality on the code (whatever level of quality you choose to test against) and so that is generally more than enough compensation for the lag in lead time, but strictly speaking, there IS a greater lead time to getting functional code using TDD.

Effectively, if you have coders that write bug-free code, TDD will be a drag on your development cycle.  The value of TDD, of course, is that there aren't any coders who can always write bug-free code, and so the cost of fixing bugs has to be factored in somewhere; in TDD, the cost of the test infrastructure is front-loaded.

Note that this is not in any way a negative thing about TDD; I'm just saying, that front-loading COULD be considered to be a "barrier to entry".  Personally, as a coder, I would say that the Return on Investment is more than worth the effort, and I think most experienced dev managers would as well.

Comment: > if you have coders that write bug-free code
then you must be living on another planet ...

Answer (score 4):

Team and/or management buy-in is the biggest obstacle in some companies.  If you're the lone developer trying to use TDD and you can't get others on the project interested, it can be very frustrating.

Of course that's not a financial barrier at all.  The biggest **perceived** financial barrier is probably time.  If you have a large code base that you need to write unit tests for, it can seem quite daunting.  Your manager (or someone above them) will question why you want to spend time writing code that will not add features/functionality to the code.  Many people don't realize that writing the tests up front (as you do in TDD) can actually *save you time*, both immediately and in the long run when you're maintaining that code.

Answer (score 4):

I think one major barrier is how it requires you to change the way you think.

Before I tried TDD, I would create a class, say Employee, then I would stub in things like FirstName, LastName, Email, etc.  Then I would write some logic and forget that I missed a few fields or something else.  And before I knew it I had a pretty complex class without knowing if those fields were ever necessary.

Also, it's a complete change from how we are used to writing software.  We are used to writing software as we receive features from the guys who sign our checks.  We are not used to writing code which doesn't compile, making it compile, then making it work to make our tests pass.

The first time you do this, you feel a bit.. well silly and stupid.  Why am I making my code intentionally fail?  It seems illogical to the "make it work" philosophy we've all been taught for so long.

A few reasons why it has failed so far where I work:

1. Most of the project at work on are older apps.  Not pre-.NET but, .NET 2.0 and in some cases .NET 1.0.
2. Some of these projects are not well factored, either because the technology wasn't there in 1.0, or it was built quickly because they needed something NOW..
3. As Jon pointed out, some things are still a PIA (pain-in-the-***) to unit test, UI, database, etc.
4. Expensive tools.  If you are only allowed to Microsoft tools, it's a high price tag to do this the "right way".  We use resharper, so it really isn't a problem.
5. Time.  I'm in a team of three guys supporting a department of 30 people.  We are considered overhead, and many of our development consists of interfacing systems together

Answer (score 1):

Yes the main barrier to entry is in your head or in the head of other programmers.

In the beginning you don't know what to srite in your tests.

The trick is to think about how your code will be used instead of focusing on how you re going to write it. Easier said than done ...

When you start to "get it", it's a bit hard to know where to stop writing tests.
You have to remember that tests prove nothing so you just can't write tests to covers all cases, you have to select the most useful ones ... and that's already a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I've certainly seen plenty of resistance. The barriers I've encountered are:

- Unit testing user interfaces (web or thick client) is tricky. I know there are *lots* of attempts to solve the problem, but I don't think any of them have made it really simple - because it's a naturally hard problem.
- At the other end, although there are various ways of making it easier to test the code involved with the database, it's still tricky and time-consuming.
- While good tests definitely speed up development overall, testing is a skill - and while you suck at it, unit testing may well be more trouble than it's worth, which means you never build up the skill...
- Managers often see it as an optional extra to development - a nice to have rather than critical. This means it's the first thing to go when the project inevitably has a resource squeeze.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a long-ish article about this a few weeks back, "[Why I write tests first](http://www.coveros.com/blog/?p=72)".

I think the biggest barrier is building the discipline to start with tests first, but I don't believe the TDD (or any practice for that matter) should be approached as an always, absolutely, 100% of the time solution.

TDD is a tool in each developer's arsenal. I tend to think it works well for me most of the time. A developer that isn't as accustomed to writing tests (first or otherwise) may it difficult to get anything done if TDD is forced on them because they can't think in terms of writing the test first.

I consider myself an experienced test-writer, but I can't always think in terms of tests. Some problems don't lend themselves well to it, or at least my head doesn't get wrapped around it some days. And some types of code (such as UI and client-side code) doesn't lend itself well to always writing tests.

If you have a team of developers that do not write tests as a matter of habit, I'd push that first. I have no problem requiring that all new code have accompanying unit tests where possible/practical. Once testing is a discipline, converting developers to TDD individually or as a team is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

One non-obvious barrier (non-obvious to me, at least) is the build infrastructure. If developers don't have control over the build process, or if the infrastructure is too baroque to be manageable, then integrating tests into the build process is going to be shunted to the side in the name of "efficiency". (Of course, in these situations it's the build infrastructure that should be shunted aside in the name of efficiency.)